# Problema con el login Raspberry Pi (Waiting for X server to shutdown (II) server terminated successfully. Closing log file.ion to X server lost

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Tengo este pequeño problema con mi raspberry, apenas la reinicie y al intentar hacer login, me regresa a la misma pantalla del login, no tira ningún error de `login` al intentar hacer `Startx` desde la terminal me regresa a la misma adjunto una imagen de lo que me retorna:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

/--------------------------------------/
Lo que arroja el `Xorg.1.log`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

/------------------------------------------------------/

Al hacer uso de `whereis python3`
me arroja esto

`python3: /use/lib/python3 /usr/lib/python3 /etc/python3.5 /usr/local/lib/python3.5`

Me da una lista entera de que unos paquetes se instalaron de forma automatica y ya no son necesarios

y para quitarlos tengo que usar `sudo apt autoremove`
que no se si sea conveniente

La unica version que tengo instalada es la de `python2.7.13` pero como ya mencione quite la version `python3`

Al querer Instalar de nuevo `python3` no me deja y me dice `El paquete python3 no esta disponible, pero algun otro hace referencia a el.`

Comment: inteta con /bin/startx or /usr/bin/startx

Comment: @JackNavaRow no tengo idea de que error sea porque en si el login solo me retorna al mismo login al autenticarme

Comment: @Bryro me sale esto mismo de la pantalla

Comment: adjunto imagen arriba acerca de esto

Comment: intenta acceder como root pueden pasar dos cosas o no tienes permiso en la carpeta o tienes la memoria de  la raspberry readonly o puedes agregarlo al grupo del tty `sudo usermod -a -G tty pi`

Comment: Lo hice pero me sigue mostrando el mismo mensage de error, es curioso porque solo reinicie la raspberry y quite python3 que no utilizaba, no se si fue por eso

Comment: @Dohko19 si!! puedes [chequear esta respuesta](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/79089) hizo lo mismo que tu

Comment: @JackNavaRow Es cierto eso, pero ahora la cosa es que no me deja instalar python3 de nuevo

Comment: @Dohko19 puedes agregar el error, pero por favor no como imagen agrega el texto

Comment: He puesto lo que llevo hasta ahorita

Comment: sudo useradd -G tty dougie;logout

Comment: intenta un `apt-get update` y luego un `apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

puede que no tenga permisos asignalos al grupo:

```
sudo usermod -a -G tty pi
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-legacy
```

o puede inicializar con el usuario pi desde

```
rc.local y agregarle el startx al archivo
```

o puedes intentar reconfigurar

```
sudo raspi-config
DISPLAY=:0 /usr/local/lib/processing-3.2.4/processing-java --sketch=/home/pi/Star --present
```

o por ultimo puedes intentar reinstalar:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xinit
sudo apt-get install lxde-core lxappearance
    sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo reboot -h 0
```

fuente:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=171843

Comment: en el raspi-config me tira un menu y sinceramente no se como poner esta parte del codigo